# Keep django pagination and search filters when submitting form on same page

Tags: django, forms, filter, pagination

I have a view which has a list of all customers on one side, which also has working pagination and search/ filter functionality.

Where I am stuck is, if I have a form & button on my list to select a customer to view on the other side of the page, and it clears my current pagination page and any filters applied to the customer list when I run the function to pick up the selected customer.

How can I have a form action = "{% url 'some_function' %}" and keep the pagination and search.
http://localhost:8000/clients/clean?page=8&search_term=nsw

Current view:

```
def customer_list_clean(request, selected = None):
    if selected != None:
       selected = Client_Customer.objects.get(id = selected)
    try:
        msg = request.GET['search_term']
    except:
        msg = ""
    clients = Client_Customer.objects.distinct().filter(Q(customer_name__contains = msg) |
                                                        Q(physical_address__street_address__contains = msg) |
                                                        Q(physical_address__suburb__suburb__contains = msg) |
                                                        Q(physical_address__suburb__post_code__contains = msg) |
                                                        Q(physical_address__suburb__region__state_abb__contains = msg)
                                                        ).order_by('customer_name')
    if msg:
        messages.success(request, (f"Customer records filtered by: {msg}"))
    found = clients.count()
    if clients.filter(confirmed= False).count()>0:
        messages.info(request, (f"Some customers records have not been validated!"))
    #Pagination
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(clients, 25)
    try:
        clients = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        clients = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        clients = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    if selected != None:
         context ={'clients':clients, 'found':found, 'msg':msg, 'selected':selected}
    else:
         context ={'clients':clients, 'found':found, 'msg':msg}
    return render(request, 'clients/client_list_clean.html',context)
```

Clients are displayed in a table (nothing special)
client_list_clean.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
  {%block body%}
    <div style="margin-left: 1.2em;margin-right: 1.2em;">
      <h1>Admin | Edit Customers</h1>
      <h4>({{found}} records found)</h4>
      <hr>
      <form action = "{% url 'clients:customer_list_clean' %}"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search records" aria-label="Search" name = "search_term">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search / Clear</button>
      </form>

      <hr>
      {%include 'client_pagination.html'%}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="container-split" style ="height: 50vh; margin-top:3px;">
      <table class = "table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Customer <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Asc</button> <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Desc</button></th>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">Type</th>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">Address
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Asc</button> <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Desc</button></th>
          <th scope="col" style="text-align:center">Details</th>
        </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>

        {% for client in clients %}
          <tr>
            {% if client.confirmed == False %}
              <td style="background-color:#d5edf6">{{client.customer_name}}</td>
              <td style="text-align:center; background-color:#d5edf6">{{client.client_type}}</td>
              <!-- <td>{{client.confirmed}}</td> -->
              {% for add in client.physical_address_set.all %}
              <td style="text-align:right; background-color:#d5edf6">{{add}}</td>
              <td style="text-align:right; background-color:#d5edf6">
                <form class="" action="{% url 'clients:customer_list_clean' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">View</button>
                </form>
              </td>
              {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
              <td>{{client.customer_name}}</td>
              <td style="text-align:center">{{client.client_type}}</td>
              {% for add in client.physical_address_set.all %}
              <td style="text-align:right">{{add}}</td>
              <td style="text-align:right">Something</td>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <hr>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
      <h3>Merge Stuff</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p>some merge stuff</p>
          {{selected.customer_name}} 
    </div>
    <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <h3>Detail stuff</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <br>
      <p>Some stuff</p>


    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  {%endblock body  %}
```

Pagination is in another template and "included" on the html page

pagination.html:

```
{% if clients.has_other_pages %}
<ul class="pagination">
  {% if clients.number >= 11 %}
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1 &search_term={{ msg }}">FIRST</a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% if clients.has_previous %}
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ clients.previous_page_number }}&search_term={{ msg }}" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if clients.number|add:'-9' > 1 %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ clients.number|add:'-10' }}&search_term={{ msg }}"><em>- 10</em></a></li>
  {% endif %}

  {% for i in clients.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if clients.number == i %}
        <li class="page-item active">
          <a class="page-link" href="#">{{ i }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        {% elif i > clients.number|add:'-10' and i < clients.number|add:'10' %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}&search_term={{ msg }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if clients.paginator.num_pages > clients.number|add:'9' %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ clients.number|add:'10' }}&search_term={{ msg }}"><em>+ 10</em></a></li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if clients.has_next %}
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ clients.next_page_number }}&search_term={{ msg }}" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}

  </ul>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all good, I worked it out.
Using an a tag instead of a form to add an additional term to the url.

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" href="?page={{ clients.number }}&search_term={{ msg }}&selected={{ client.id }}">View</a>
```

views.py

```
try:
    print(request.GET['selected'])
except:
    pass
```

I am yet to do something with the selected id, but I now have it in the function none the less.